# fsockopen unable to connect error with remote css file

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm trying to get HTTP response headers of all images/css/js files used in a remote web page.When I use

`fsockopen('mydomain.com',80,$errsno,$errstr,20)`

it works.But when I try to do the same for a css link in my webpage, like,

```
fsockopen('mydomain.com/style.css',80,$errno,$errstr,20)
```

it returns error

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to mydomain.com/style.css
```

Isn't it possible to connect to remote file like `css or image` files?

But the file is there in my server.I was hoping to get the `response headers,file size,response time` etc.Can't I do that this way? Any hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fsockopen()` doesn't speak HTTP, you'd have to write a valid HTTP request to the socket after opening it as in your first example yourself. Minimal form would be:

```
GET /style.css HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
```

followed by an extra empty line.

Or you could use PEAR HTTP_Request2 package if you don't want to speak raw HTTP:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.php

Comment: Thanks for the response.Let me try it :)

Comment: Thank you @Hartmut Holzgraefe, I understand now ! :)